# How can I write a script to auto sort a column with formulas and update every time a change is made?

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm tracking the percentage of different stocks in column 3 and I want them to be automatically sorted by descending order every time the data is updated. The data in column 3 is formulaic. They are not text. How can I write this script?

[Spreadsheet Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X0WOk6MVVh0Kb1cpMQn2B2U8bqgKDieETtRaF7Gnssc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60820005/5632629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tested on your sheet and works:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("TOP PICKS");
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z");

function onOpen(e)  {
  range.sort([{column: 3, ascending: true}]);
}
```